# How to make histogram using this data?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, histogram

[image: code]

```
2005.0     7
2006.0     8
2007.0     6
2008.0    13
2009.0     8
2010.0     6
2011.0    10
2012.0    16
2013.0    17
2014.0    19
2015.0    18
2016.0    19
2017.0    20
2018.0    18
2019.0    15
```

I sliced my excel file and used value_counts() so that I got the data like picture (2005.0 - 2019.0 are the years, and right side is counted number)

Finally, I tried to make histogram but I failed. Could you give me a help? I want a histogram with on the x-axis the year, and the y-axis the frequency.

Comment: histogram shows x-axis as the right side(number) ...

Comment: Well in that case just: `.plot.bar()`?

Comment: Success. You are genius. Thank you !!

Comment: oh..It is  not histogram but It's okay thank you

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking to do is create a bar chart since you've now made it into a data frame which has categories (years) and values. You can do so with pandas. 
For reference: [Difference Between Histogram and Bar Graph](https://keydifferences.com/difference-between-histogram-and-bar-graph.html)

```
import pandas as pd

# makes visualization render in notebook
%matplotlib inline

# create dataframe with columns 'year' and 'value'
df = pd.DataFrame({'year':[2005, 2006, 2007, 2008], 'value':[7,8,6,13]})

# create bar chart
df.plot.bar(x='year', y = 'value')
```

Other packages that render bar charts:

- Seaborn: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html
- Matplotlib: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html
- Bokeh: http://docs.bokeh.org/en/1.0.0/docs/user_guide/categorical.html

For a histogram, which shows the distribution of a single variable:

```
original_df.hist(column = 'values')
```